# Custom Control for Line

Tags: c#, line, custom-controls

I want to design a custom Control for Line (vertical or horizontal line)
basic usercontrol is rectangle and not suitable for line 
what s your idea about line control?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question.

Comment: Might want to concentrate on grammar as well, i dont see much use for a line control...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new UserControl Drag over to the designer surface, set the **Height** property to around 2px if you want horizontal line, or set the **Width** property to around 2px if you want vertical line.

Answer (score 0):

If you changing the controls width and height you are able to adjust the line.
Just create a UserControl and put below code inside it.

```
  bool horizontal= false;
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (horizontal)
            {
                Height = 1;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Width, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                Width = 1;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 1, Height);
            }
        }
```